# C# Execute a formload event when another form has closed

Tags: c#

I have an application I am currently building which is a mini CRM.

Currently, when form 1 loads it executes a method to retrieve the customer data

```
  private void CustomerOverViewV1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
CustomerManagement.GetCustomerPoliciesForOverview();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            CustomerManagement.GetCustomerOverViewV1();

            CustomerManagement.GetCustomerOverviewNote();

            SQLBilling.GetOverviewBillingDetails();



        }
```

i load up form 2 to update the customers details click okay which executes another method to update the details to the database and then have this.close(). However when i have run this.close() I would like to execute the above code snippet again automatically so that the changes are reflected immediately but i just cannot work it out - Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: `i load up form 2` How do you do this? from the Form1? Can you share that code? Is this a WindowsForms application?

Comment: Define "cannot work it out", what happens when you try? Exceptions?

Comment: Apologies on form 1 is a button called updateCustomerDetails which behind this button is form1 form1 = new form1 form1.showdialog()

Comment: One option is that you may want to extract the code in your `CustomerOverView_Load()` into its own method, then call that method during `CustomerOverView_Load()` and during close of your other dialog box.  Also, the `Thread.Sleep()` hints at the fact that you're waiting for data to be pulled?  If that's the case you may want to incorporate asynchronous calls (https://grantwinney.com/using-async-await-and-task-to-keep-the-winforms-ui-more-responsive/)

Comment: The Load event can fire only once.  Move this code into a separate private method, call it both from the Load event handler and the method that calls ShowDialog().